# Convert DTO to Domain models and back with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, dto

I am new in Java so I want ask you if exist some pretty solution by lambda which convert One type object to another?

I had function in service:

```
public List<MyObjectDto> findAll() {
    List<MyObject> list = repository.findAll();
    return list.someMagicToConvertToDtoObjectsInList();
}
```

Any ideas for that?

Comment: what type needs to be converted to what type?

Comment: No. There is no magic. Write a converter. You could look at something like [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) - but it may be a little beyond your current level.

Comment: @Salman My custom objects with properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no magic here but you can stream the list and then implement a `map` function to transform from the domain representation to the DTO representation.

For example, given a domain object with `id, firstName, lastName` and a DTO with `id, name` (where `name` is a concatenation of `firstName` and `lastName`) the following code ...

```
List<MyObject> domain = new ArrayList<>();
domain.add(new MyObject(1, "John", "Smith"));
domain.add(new MyObject(1, "Bob", "Bailey"));

// using the verbose statement of function (rahter than a lambda) 
// to make it easier to see how the map function works
List<MyDto> asDto = domain.stream().map(new Function<MyObject, MyDto>() {
    @Override
    public MyDto apply(MyObject s) {
        // a simple mapping from domain to dto
        return new MyDto(s.getId(), s.getFirstName() + " " + s.getLastName());
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(asDto);
```

... prints out:

```
[
    MyDto{id=1, name='John Smith'}, 
    MyDto{id=1, name='Bob Bailey'}
]
```

Of course, the above use of an anonymous class looks somewhat out of place when using `stream()` so here's the same code expressed using a lambda:

```
List<MyDto> asDto = domain.stream().map(
        s -> new MyDto(s.getId(), s.getFirstName() + " " + s.getLastName())
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for example but I'm using my custom objects with properties, and I need map properties

Comment: I provided a String example because I'm not familiar with your "custom object with properties" but the approach in the above example is valid regardless of what type the `List` is. The lambda accepts an instance of your domain object and emits an instance of your DTO, the implementation of the lambda simply adapts one to the other. I have just updated the answer to show more clearly how the map funciton can transform your domain into your DTO.

Comment: What's with the hideous anonymous `class`? Why use a Java 8 `Stream` and then not use a lambda?

Comment: @BoristheSpider my original answer used a lambda, the OP's response made me suspect that this made the answer less understandable so I edited to add the anonymous Function class with the following comment to explain why I did so: "// using the verbose statement of function (rahter than a lambda) to make it easier to see how the map function works"

Comment: Fair enough - bit it's mentioning that they are **not** equivalent. A lambda would use `invokedynamic` and be potentially significantly more performant.

Answer (score 8):

By using streams, you can use the following:

```
public List<MyObjectDTO> findAll() {
    List<MyObject> list = repository.findAll();
    return list.stream()
            .map(MyObjectDTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

For this to work, your DTO class will need to have a constructor which accepts your domain model:

```
public class MyObjectDTO {

    // fields

    public MyObjectDTO(MyObject myObject) {
        // map MyObject fields to MyObjectDTO fields
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

An alternative to the parametric constructor is encapsulating the conversion in a method, for example:

```
public class Service {    

    public List<MyObjectDto> findAll() {
        List<MyObject> list = repository.findAll();
        return list.stream()
                .map(Service::convert)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }

    private MyObjectDTO convert(MyObject myObject) {
        // conversion here
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I looking for, but is possible do that without parametric constructor in MyObjectDTO?

Comment: If you are willing to encapsulate the conversion in a method, you can do:

Comment: Please disregard my comment above. You can achieve it if you are willing to encapsulate the conversion in a method. See my edited answer.