# How to handle partial updates to an Entity in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are doing partial update on an Entity using Spring Boot as follows, is there a more elegant way as if the Entity contains 50+ attributes then its really painful to handle

```
public Foo updateFoo(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Foo fooInput) {
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Foo not found for this id: " + id));

    if (fooInput.getCaption() != null) {
        foo.setCaption(fooInput.getCaption());
    }   

    if (fooInput.getBar() != null) {
        foo.setBar(fooInput.getBar());
    }   
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is a DTO-Model conversion utility, you can find an introduction to `modelmapper` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44561593/9304616).

Answer (score 2):

You can use to [JSON Patch](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch) library with Spring Framework. [Implementing JSON Patch in a Spring Boot Application](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-json-patch#json-patch-boot)

This is an implementation of RFC 6902 (JSON Patch) and RFC 7386 (JSON Merge Patch) written in Java, which uses Jackson (2.2.x) at its core.

> JSON Patch is a format for describing changes to a JSON document. It can be used to avoid sending a whole document when only a part has changed. When used in combination with the HTTP PATCH method, it allows partial updates for HTTP APIs in a standards compliant way. The patch documents are themselves JSON documents. [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) is specified in RFC 6902 from the IETF.

Answer (score 0):

If the non-updated fields are not present in JSON, you can do it like that:

```
Foo updateFoo(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody String json) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Foo not found for this id: " + id));

    ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.readerForUpdating(foo);
    
    foo = objectReader.readValue(json);
    return foo;
}
```

If non-updated fields are set to null (or are not present in JSON), you can use the function below. Unfortunately, I could not ingore the null values during deserialization with Jackson annotations, so I deleted the null values myself.

```
Foo updateFoo(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody ObjectNode node) throws IOException {
    Iterator<String> i = node.fieldNames();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String field = i.next();
        if(node.get(field).isNull()) {
            node.remove(field);
        }
    }
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Foo not found for this id: " + id));
    ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.readerForUpdating(foo);
    foo = objectReader.readValue(node);
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Furter to Robert Żyłan's answer, you can simplify your code a bit.
As an addition, you can use either of two here: `Map<String, Object> fields` or `String json`, so your service method may look like this:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
@Transactional
public Foo save(long id, Map<String, Object> fields) throws JsonMappingException {
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findById(id)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Foo not found for this id: " + id));

    return objectMapper.updateValue(foo , fields);
}
```

As a second solution you could use `Reflection` to map only properties that exist in a Map of values that was sent, so your service method may look like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Foo save(long id, Map<String, Object> fields) {

    Foo foo = fooRepository.findById(id)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Foo not found for this id: " + id));

    fields.keySet()
            .forEach(k -> {
                Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(LocationProduct.class, "set" + StringUtils.capitalize(k));
                if (method != null) {
                    ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, foo, fields.get(k));
                }
            });
    return foo;
}
```

Second solution allows you to insert some additional business logic into mapping process, might be conversions or calculations ect.

Also unlike finding reflection field `Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Foo.class, k);` by name and than making it accessible, finding property's setter actually calls setter method that might contain additional logic to be executed and prevents from setting value to private properties.